# Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1) using log() logarithm

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

So when I use the `log` function in my fortran90 code it throws the following compile time error:

```
newtonf90.f90:21:

f = ((x - 2.d0)**2) \xE2\x88\x92 log(x)
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

Note: using `gfortran`

So, what is the mistake that I am making?

The entire code:

```
implicit none
double precision p0,p,df,f,tol
integer imax,i

p0=1.d0
imax=70
tol=0.0001
do i=1, imax
   p = p0 - f(p0) / df(p0)
   write(2,*) i , p , dabs(p0-p)
   if (dabs(p0-p) .lt. tol) stop
   p0=p
enddo
stop
end program newton

function f(x)
implicit none
double precision x,f
f = ((x - 2.d0)**2) − log(x)
return
end function f

function df(x)
implicit none
double precision x,df
df=2*(x - 2.d0) - 1/x
return
end function df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character before "log" is not a minus sign. Delete it and write a proper "-" in its place.

Comment: I'm curious - which language/keyboard/editor is it that allows a dash to be accidentally entered, instead of the minus sign?

Comment: I suppose that an accidental copy-paste is the likely source of error. When passing the code via a HTML page or a pdf document this can happen easily. A plain text editor has no reason to complain about a dash.